# Imprimir código EPL com javascript

Tags: javascript, impressão, impressora

Estou fazendo alguns teste com a impressora **Zebra GC420T** usando a linguagem **EPL** para gerar o texto e código de barras.

Como posso através do javascript mandar a impressora imprimir o seguinte código?

```
N
q812
S2
A50,0,0,1,1,1,N,"Example 1 0123456789"
A50,50,0,2,1,1,N,"Example 2 0123456789"
A50,100,0,3,1,1,N,"Example 3 0123456789"
A50,150,0,4,1,1,N,"Example 4 0123456789"
A50,200,0,5,1,1,N,"EXAMPLE 5 0123456789"
A50,300,0,3,2,2,R,"Example 6 0123456789"
LO25,600,750,20
B50,800,0,3,3,7,200,B,"998152-001"
P1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O javascript não tem acesso direto a impressora do usuário, sendo assim é necessário utilizar de outro meio para essa impressão.
Uma forma de se fazer isso utilizando javascript é com o applet [jzebra](https://code.google.com/p/jzebra/)

Exemplo de código:

```
<input type=button onClick="print()" value="Print">
<applet id="qz" name="QZ Print Plugin" code="qz.PrintApplet.class" archive="./qz-print.jar" width="100" height="100">
      <param name="printer" value="zebra">
</applet>

<script>
      function print() {
         var qz = document.getElementById('qz');
         qz.append('A37,503,0,1,2,3,N,PRINTED USING QZ-PRINT\n');
         // ZPLII
         // qz.append('^XA^FO50,50^ADN,36,20^FDPRINTED USING QZ-PRINT^FS^XZ');  
         qz.print();
      }
</script>
```

Segue o link da biblioteca de implementação do mesmo: [Tutorial Web Applet jzebra](http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/wiki/TutorialWebApplet).

Existem outras formas de se alcançar o esperado, por exemplo, já fiz um programa em C# que era invocado quando o usuário entrasse em uma URI `PRINTAR://A37,503,1,0,0,N,XXX` recebendo os parâmetros para impressão pela mesma.

Para que o programa fosse invocado dessa forma, o mesmo criava chaves no registro do usuário durante sua instalação, como o exemplo a seguir:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   PRINTAR
      (Default) = "URL:Print Protocol"
      URL Protocol = ""
      DefaultIcon
         (Default) = "printar.exe,1"
      shell
         open
            command
               (Default) = "C:\Program Files\Print\printar.exe" "%1"
```

e então era invocado pela utilização do `window.open('PRINTAR://XXXXXX');` no javascript.

Comment: Desse modo do applet parece ser bem interessante, fiz alguns testes mas não obtive muitos resultados, ele manda pra impressora e no status fica marcado como "imprimindo" http://demo.qzindustries.com/

Comment: Consegui imprimir um teste com o applet, agora só preciso adaptar ao meu código :D

Comment: @silvioAndorinha ótimo, desculpa não tinha visto teu comentário anterior, qual era o problema? Comente aqui que dai eu acrescento na resposta!

Comment: Não estava usando o plugin da forma adequada. Mas aí segui esse tutorial https://code.google.com/p/jzebra/wiki/TutorialWebApplet e consegui